# How to calculate $\int \frac{1}{x^{2}-1}dx$

Tags: calculus

I got different answers when I use substitution of $x=\sec(t)$ or split the term. Also as I calculated, the answer is $\frac{1}{2}(\ln(x-1)-\ln(x+1))+c$, while the answer given by Wolfram Alpha is $\frac{1}{2}(\ln(1-x)-\ln(x+1))+c$. Where is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: some condition must be mentioned in the question about x.

Comment: $\int\frac{1}{x-1}\ dx=\ln|x-1|+C$ **not** $\ln(x-1)+C.$  Then, $|x-1|=|1-x|.$

Comment: The correct form is $\frac{1}{2}(\ln |x-1|-\ln|x+1|)$ the rest depends on the interval where $x$ lies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In real calculus, $\displaystyle\int\frac1{x-a}=\ln|x-a|+K$

and we know $\displaystyle|b|=|-b|$ for any real $b$

Answer (score 1):

Just know that: $$\dfrac{1}{x^2-1}=\dfrac{-1}{2(x+1)}+\dfrac{1}{2(x-1)}$$

Now, use the fact that $$\int \dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{x+1}=\log |x+1|+\mathrm{constant.}$$
and

$$\int \dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{x-1}=\log |x-1|+\mathrm{constant.}$$